Establishing dynamic links between, plugins of output to input
In the resultwindow, we have two tabs plugin graph(to generate plugins) and user interface tab. when we load the addPlugin.py code, the plugins will generate based on how many time we generate. The plugins are with Input1, Input2 and output buttons. The main functionality is : when we click on output button and also input button it should establish a link and in the user interface also it needs to process the data. So that, when we give input1 and input2 it will needs to generate the output, and the output should automatically links to the respective input based on the functionality link we did in the plugins linkage.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import os
import importlib.util

line = None
class ResultWindows(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, ui_main_window=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.ui_main_window = ui_main_window
        self.config(bg='white')
        self.plugin_horizontal_gap = 250
        self.input_output_gap = 150
        self.plugins = []
        self.temp_line = None
        self.link_start = None
        self.link_end = None
        self.selected_input = None
        self.selected_output = None

    def add_plugin(self, inputLabels, outputLabels, plugin_name):
        start_x = 10 + len(self.plugins) self.plugin_horizontal_gap if self.plugins else 10
        start_y, button_width, button_height, text_padding = 10, 20, 20, 5
    
        input_start_x = start_x
        output_start_x = start_x + self.input_output_gap
    
        self.create_text(start_x + self.input_output_gap / 2, start_y, text=plugin_name, font=("Arial", 14, "bold"), fill="blue", tags="plugin")
    
        for i, label in enumerate(inputLabels):
            input_y = start_y + 20 + (i * (button_height + 10))
            input_btn = self.create_rectangle(input_start_x, input_y, input_start_x + button_width, input_y + button_height, fill="green", tags=("input", f"input_{plugin_name}_{i}"))
            self.create_text(input_start_x + button_width + text_padding * 2, input_y + button_height / 2, text=label, anchor="w", font=("Arial", 12), tags="plugin")
            self.tag_bind(input_btn, "<Button-3>", lambda event, name=f"input_{plugin_name}_{i}": self.finalize_link(event, name=name))
    
        for i, label in enumerate(outputLabels):
            output_y = start_y + 20 + (i * (button_height + 10))
            output_btn = self.create_rectangle(output_start_x, output_y, output_start_x + button_width, output_y + button_height, fill="red", tags=("output", f"output_{plugin_name}_{i}"))
            self.create_text(output_start_x - text_padding * 2, output_y + button_height / 2, text=label, anchor="e", font=("Arial", 12), tags="plugin")
            self.tag_bind(output_btn, "<Button-1>", lambda event, name=f"output_{plugin_name}_{i}": self.start_link(event, name=name))
    
            self.plugins.append(plugin_name)

    def start_link(self, event, name):
        self.link_start = (event.x, event.y)
        # Create a temporary line if desired
        self.temp_line = self.create_line(self.link_start[0], 
        self.link_start[1], event.x, event.y, fill="blue", dash=(4, 2))


    def finalize_link(self, event, name):
        if self.temp_line and self.link_start:
            # Draw the final line
            self.create_line(self.link_start[0], self.link_start[1], event.x, event.y, fill="red", width=2)
            # Cleanup
            self.delete(self.temp_line)
            self.temp_line = None
            self.link_start = None

    def clear_plugins(self):
         self.delete("plugin")
         self.plugins.clear()

    def reset_selection(self, input_or_output):
         # Reset the selection based on input_or_output argument
         if input_or_output == "output" and self.selected_output_tag:
             self.itemconfig(self.selected_output_tag, fill="red")  
        # Reset to default color
        elif input_or_output == "input" and self.selected_input_tag:
             self.itemconfig(self.selected_input_tag, fill="green") # Reset to default color


    def update_link(self, event):
        if self.temp_line and self.link_start:
            # Update temporary line's end point to follow the mouse
            self.coords(self.temp_line, self.link_start[0], self.link_start[1], event.x, event.y)

        
class DragManager():
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_x = 0
        self.start_y = 0
        self.active_widget = None

    def add_draggable(self, widget):
        widget.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event, widget=widget: self.on_drag_start(event, widget))
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_drag)
        widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_drop)
        widget.configure(cursor='hand1')

    def on_drag_start(self, event, widget):
        self.active_widget = widget
        self.start_x = event.x_root
        self.start_y = event.y_root

    def on_drag(self, event):
        if self.active_widget:
            delta_x = event.x_root - self.start_x
            delta_y = event.y_root - self.start_y
            x = self.active_widget.winfo_x() + delta_x
            y = self.active_widget.winfo_y() + delta_y
            self.active_widget.place(x=x, y=y)
            self.start_x = event.x_root
            self.start_y = event.y_root

    def on_drop(self, event):
        self.active_widget = None
        return True

class Canvas_Manager:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.links = []
        self.current_link = None
        self.bind_events()
    

    def on_canvas_right_click(self, event):
        item = self.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        self.gettags(item)
        # Process tags to determine if an output button was clicked and handle accordingly

    def bind_events(self):
        self.canvas.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.start_link)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.draw_link)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.end_link)

    def start_link(self, event):
        self.current_link = [event.x, event.y]

    def draw_link(self, event):
        if self.current_link:
           self.canvas.delete("link")
           self.canvas.create_line(self.current_link[0], self.current_link[1], event.x, event.y, tag="link", fill="red", width=2)

    def end_link(self, event):
        self.current_link = None
    
class Ui_MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("MainWindow")
        self.root.geometry("800x600")

        self.tabWidget = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.tabWidget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabWidget)
        self.tabWidget.add(self.tab1, text="Plugin Graph")

        self.groupBox1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.tab1, text="Create Configuration")
        self.groupBox1.pack(side="top", anchor="nw", padx=10, pady=10)

        self.pushButton_2 = ttk.Button(self.groupBox1, text="New",command=self.clear_frames)
        self.pushButton_2.pack(side="left")

        # Combobox to display pyc files
        self.comboBox = ttk.Combobox(self.groupBox1)
        self.comboBox.pack(side="left")


        self.groupBox2 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.tab1, text="Load/Save Configuration")
        self.groupBox2.pack(side="top", anchor="nw", padx=10, pady=10)

        self.comboBox_2 = ttk.Combobox(self.groupBox2)
        self.comboBox_2.pack(side="left")

        self.pushButton_3 = ttk.Button(self.groupBox2, text="Save")
        self.pushButton_3.pack(side="left")

        self.groupBox3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.tab1, text="PluginGroupBox")
        self.groupBox3.pack(side="top", anchor="nw", padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas = ResultWindows(self.groupBox3)
        self.canvas = ResultWindows(self.groupBox3, ui_main_window=self)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)     
        self.message_box = tk.Text(self.root, height=2, width=50)
        self.message_box.pack(side="bottom", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabWidget)
        self.tabWidget.add(self.tab2, text="User Interface")
        self.groupBox4 = tk.LabelFrame(self.tab2, text="UIGroupBox")
        self.groupBox4.pack(side="top", anchor="nw", padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=True)
        self.pushButton_4 = ttk.Button(self.tab2, text="Start")
        self.pushButton_4.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)  # Adjusted position
        self.pushButton_5 = ttk.Button(self.tab2, text="Hide All Doc Pins")
        self.pushButton_5.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)  # Adjusted position
        self.pushButton = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Exit", command=self.exit_application)
        self.pushButton.pack(side="bottom", anchor="se", padx=10, pady=10)  # Anchor to bottom-right corner
        self.tabWidget.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.on_tab_change)
        self.comboBox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.load_selected_file)
        # list to keep tracks of frames added
        self.frames_groupbox3 = []
        self.frames_groupbox4 = []
        # Container frame for draggable frames
        self.container_frame4 = tk.Frame(self.groupBox4)
        self.container_frame4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        # Create a single instance of DragManager
        self.drag_manager = DragManager()
        self.canvas_manager = Canvas_Manager(self.canvas)
        # Populate Combobox with DLL files
        self.populate_pyc_files()   
    def populate_pyc_files(self):
        # Get the current directory
        current_directory = os.getcwd()
        #List all files in the directory
        pyc_files = [file for file in os.listdir(current_directory) if file.endswith(".py")]
        # Populate Combobox with PYC file names
        self.comboBox["values"] = pyc_files
    def on_tab_change(self, event):
        current_tab = self.tabWidget.select()
        tab_text = self.tabWidget.tab(current_tab, "text")
        if tab_text == "User Interface":
            self.root.title("User Interface Tab")
        elif tab_text == "Plugin Graph":
            self.root.title("Plugin Graph Tab")
    def clear_frames(self):
        # Destroy frames in groupBox3
        for frame in self.frames_groupbox3:
            frame.destroy()
        # Clear the list
        self.frames_groupbox3 = []
        # Destroy frames in groupBox4
        for frame in self.frames_groupbox4:
            frame.destroy()
        # Clear the list
        self.frames_groupbox4 = []
    def update_ui_tab(self):
        # Clear existing content in the UI group box
        for widget in self.groupBox4.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        # Add labels for each plugin configured
        for i, plugin_name in enumerate(self.pluginCanvas.plugins, start=1):
            tk.Label(self.groupBox4, text=f"Plugin {i}: {plugin_name}", font=("Arial", 12)).pack()
    def clear_plugins(self):
        self.canvas.clear_plugins()
    def load_selected_file(self, event=None):
        # Create a new frame
        frame4 = ttk.Frame(self.container_frame4, relief="solid", borderwidth=5)
        frame4.pack(side="left", padx=10)
        self.frames_groupbox4.append(frame4)  # Store reference to the frame
        # Make the frame draggable
        self.drag_manager.add_draggable(frame4)
        #Call canvas events to establish visual connection
        self.canvas_manager.bind_events()
        selected_file = self.comboBox.get()
        print(selected_file)
        if selected_file:
            try:
                module_name = os.path.splitext(selected_file)[0]
                module_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), selected_file)
                spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
                module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
                spec.loader.exec_module(module)
            
                main_window = module.MainWindow(frame4)
                main_window.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

                inputs = main_window.get_inputs()
                outputs = main_window.get_outputs()

                self.canvas.add_plugin(inputLabels=inputs, outputLabels=outputs,plugin_name=selected_file.title())

                except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to load file: {e}")
        
    def exit_application(self):
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    ui = Ui_MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

##code for addPlugin.py to load the plugins####
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    
        # Input fields
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Input 1")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.Input1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Input1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Input 2")
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.Input2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Input2.grid(row=0, column=3)

    # Buttons
        self.Addbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Add", command=self.add_numbers)
        self.Addbtn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)


        self.Clrbtn = tk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.clear_inputs)
        self.Clrbtn.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)

    # Output field
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Output")
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=0)

       self.Output = tk.Entry(self)
       self.Output.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3)

    def add_numbers(self):
        try:
           num1 = int(self.Input1.get())
           num2 = int(self.Input2.get())
           result = num1 + num2
           self.Output.delete(0, tk.END)
           self.Output.insert(0, str(result))
           self.result_window.update_result(result)
        except ValueError:
           messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please enter valid numbers.")

    def clear_inputs(self):
        self.Input1.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.Input2.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.Output.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.result_window.update_result(0)

    def get_inputs(self):
        return [self.label1.cget("text"), self.label2.cget("text")]

    def get_outputs(self):
        return [self.label.cget("text")]



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Addition")

    main_window = MainWindow(root)
    main_window.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

    root.mainloop()

###code for setting up of .pyc file to load the addplugin.py, file name is .setup.py####
import compileall
import sys

def compile_py_to_pyc(file_path):
    try:
        compileall.compile_file(file_path, force=True)
        print(f"Successfully compiled {file_path} to .pyc")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error compiling {file_path}: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python setup.py <file_path>")
        sys.exit(1)

    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    compile_py_to_pyc(file_path)

for running setup.py, we used python setup.py addPlugin.py ###.
It generates .pyc file.

Please provide us some code, and show errors. So, we can help you with that

You should share some example code, of the project that is giving you this issue. Also, you speak of elements you're clicking, so please add some description of the libraries or frameworks that you're using, and consider adding a tag to your question for it as well, to attract the attention of people that are familiar with them.

I just added the code. Please check it
